# Why is my SATA 2 SSD dog slow?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, ssd, performance

I have an SSD drive (not NVME or M2, just the ordinary SATA type). Sorry, I cant tell the exact model but it is one of the well known brands, not some unknown origin. I am using it since 2016. Capacity 120 GB.

My motherboard is GA-78LMT-USB3 (rev. 6.0) so its SATA 2 (and not 3). However SATA 2 is still limited at 375 MB/s which is still a lot more than what I get out of the drive.

I tried testing its write throughput and I cant get more than ~90 MB/s when I write several gigabytes. If I write only ~1 GB then the throughput is more like ~160 MB/s.

I used `fstrim -a` to no effect. What more can I do, short of replacing the drive?

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test oflag=sync bs=64MB count=100 status=progress 
skopiowane 6400000000 bajtów (6,4 GB, 6,0 GiB), 86 s, 74,5 MB/s
100+0 przeczytanych rekordów
100+0 zapisanych rekordów
skopiowane 6400000000 bajtów (6,4 GB, 6,0 GiB), 85,8981 s, 74,5 MB/s
arkadiusz@arkadiusz-desktop:~/Pobrane$ 

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test2 oflag=sync bs=64MB count=10 status=progress 
skopiowane 512000000 bajtów (512 MB, 488 MiB), 3 s, 168 MB/s
10+0 przeczytanych rekordów
10+0 zapisanych rekordów
skopiowane 640000000 bajtów (640 MB, 610 MiB), 3,79625 s, 169 MB/s
```

[image: SMART data of the SSD]

Comment: Not exactly surprising for a drive as old and small as that.

Comment: Are you saying that replacing it with a new one will solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the drive is worn out and slowing down - which is typical for SSDs.

Comment: What does SMART say?  It should be able to tell you both the model and provide wear stats on the drive.  Maybe a command like "sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda"

Comment: SMART shows nothing, pasted it into the question.

Comment: SMART does not show nothing. It shows that the drive is old, possibly nearly worn out and probably ready for replacement.